# Extend one properties file to another properties file

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

Having two properties file that has some common property in it, just want to segregate those common properties in another file and include this property file to existing properties files.

```
first.properties file
a.city=newyork
a.country=usa
first.street=crew

second.properties file
a.city=newyork
a.country=usa
second.street=brew
```

I want to create a separate common.properties file that can be extended in other properties file just like...

```
common.properties file
a.city=newyork
a.country=usa

first.properties file
include = common.properties
first.street=crew

second.properties file
include = common.properties
second.street=brew
```

I have tried with this reference but this didnt help https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you working specifically with apache commons-configuration, or do you want any solution that would work with `java.util.Properties` ?

Comment: With `java.util.Properties`, a naive solution would be to load the specific file, check its `include` value, then in another Properties load first the included file, then the specific file (in order for the specific value to overwrite the common ones, and not the other way around). I'm saying naive because it requires to read the specific file twice, there might be a way to avoid that.

Comment: @Aaron
any solution would be fine that work with java.util.Properties

Comment: @Khan I don't believe what you are trying to achieve can be implemented by properties files, the best you can do is keep the separate files e.g. "common.properties" and "specific1.properties", "specific2.properties" and then load common first and then the specific ones which would ensure you have your common properties and the specific properties overriding those wherever needed.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, I used the way as described.... thats the only option i left with...

Comment: Thanks @dShringi